# Change "Internet Protocol Version 4" DNS in windows with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, automation, dns

I usually change my internet connections DNS in Internet Protocol Version 4 and now I want to automate it with python to set my setting and also be able to clear that set DNS, could you help me with that please.

I used python "winreg" library and I failed but I think there are more better ways.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with Python? If you know how to change the registry, and you've already done so... aren't you done?

Comment: @Chris I have a python code and I want to add this to my base code. Also I want to learn this with python

Answer (score 1):

You can use the win32api and win32con modules to modify the DNS settings in Windows. Here's an example code to change the DNS server to Google's public DNS servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4):

```
import win32api
import win32con

# Set DNS server addresses
dns_servers = ['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4']

# Open the network adapter key in the registry
key = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(
    win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Tcpip\\Parameters\\Interfaces\\{<adapter_guid>}",
    0,
    win32con.KEY_ALL_ACCESS
)

# Set the DNS server addresses
win32api.RegSetValueEx(key, 'NameServer', 0, win32con.REG_MULTI_SZ, dns_servers)

# Close the registry key
win32api.RegCloseKey(key)
```

Make sure to replace <adapter_guid> with the GUID of your network adapter. You can find it by running the following command in the command prompt:

```
ipconfig /all
```

Look for the "Ethernet adapter" or "Wireless LAN adapter" section that corresponds to your active network connection and find the "GUID" value.
I hope this way would work for you!